# Terraform state rm command

Tags: azure, templates, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a azure terraform template to create a resource group and a vnet. I have run
terraform plan and then apply . Created the environment.
Now, for testing purpose some one has created a storage account through Azure portal in the same resource group. Ever since then, whenever I run terraform plan, its showing the resource group to be destroyed state.

Hence I renamed the resource group in the template, and ran the terraform plan. its showing new resource group creation along with the deletion of existing one.

I know this is happening , because terraform state file is having the information of the existing resource group. I am trying to remove the existing resource group from the state file by the below command

terraform state rm azurem_resource_group.rg *<"subscription ID of the resource group">*

I am getting the below error

[image]

Is there a way to remove the reference of existing resource in the state file ,so that it doesnt end up in deletion?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the reference of the existing resource group in the state file, you could run it without providing the specific resource id.

```
terraform state rm azurerm_resource_group.rg
```

[image]

You also could show the state with `terraform state list`.